# Is it possible to successfully import a corrupted CSV file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I work in a company where we frequently do imports for new clients who start using our product. Sometimes we receive files with lot of corrupted data like a particular column expected to contain time like

```
TIME
----------
17:12:55
22:32:38
12:16:56
```

but some rows holds some useless data besides actual data like

```
TIME
----------
17:12:55
22:32:38kldjfakdfhehdkdfjdkff
12:16:56
```

It happens with multiple columns and for multiple rows. For some rows that useless data is appended and for some prepended. My question is whether such corrupted data can be filtered and can we successfully import the files or such files are useless and we should demand for new file to our client.

Comment: How are you importing? SSIS? If so you can redirect error rows to a holding table for inspection instead of failing the whole import.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

In my ex-company we programmed a C# script that imported CSV even if they were corrupt. Basically we imported row by row, column by column into a staging table. If a rows was half broken, we just imported as much as possible. Then later the data quality check was applied in SQL. Like this it was possible to import all rubbish CSV files received from our clients without always having a failing SSIS import.

Therefore, if you have time and patience, you can write a similar C# import (a lot of examples online available). Our import was generic, so that each possible file can be imported with the same script, the business logic of the file (column mapping) defined in an SQL table.

The staging table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE [Staging].[FilesStaging](
    [FilesStagingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProcessingID] [int] NULL,
    [ImportProcessingID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessingTypeID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ExcelSheet] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col4] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col5] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col6] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col7] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col8] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col9] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col10] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col11] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col12] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col13] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col14] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Col15] [varchar](255) NULL,
    ...
```